# How can i create another menu in my content folder in a .md file using HUGO?

Tags: go, hugo

I trying to create a different menu than my main menu on another page, i write my code in the config.toml but i have no idea how can i put in my .md files.[there is my code in the config.toml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vaeE4.png)

```
    [menu]

#Main Menu

[[menu.main]]
name        = "Inicio"
identifier  = "menu.Inicio"
url         = "/"
weight      = 1
[[menu.main]]
name        = "Nosotros"
url         = "/about-us"
weight      = 2
parent      = "menu.Inicio
```

[and there is my code in my .md file for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F00Ky.png)

Comment: The doocs should be helpful: https://gohugo.io/content-management/menus/. First, declare multiple menus (`menu = ['main', 'pasto']`). Then add the links to the appropriate menu, e.g. menu.main, menu.pasto

Comment: Thanks for the answer,  for example if i want a global menu only for my products
I need to create in my config file 
`[[menu.product]]
name = "Category"
identifier = "menu.cat"
weight = 1
//// and 
[[menu.product]]
name = "Use"
url = "/"
weight = 2
parent = "menu.cat"
And in my .md file i call my menu like this.
menu = ['product','cat']`

?

Comment: Sorry, I realize I was vague in the comment. You declare the menus in the site's config.toml file. I'm adding an answer because the formatting is lost in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

**Option one:**

In your site's `config.toml` file, you can declare multiple menus. Hugo doesn't require this, but it's helpful to list them in one place:

`menu = ['main', 'pasto']`

Then in the content pages you can assign that content item to one or multiple menus. In the frontmatter, for example `content/posts/first-page.md`:

```
...
menu:
  main:
    title: "First page"
    weight: 1
---
```

For multiple menus, add another menu entry:

```
...
menu:
  products:
    title: "Second product"
    weight: 2
  main:
    title: "See our Second product"
    weight: 3
---
```

**Option two:**

Do not create menu entries in the content files. Instead, you can add links to the menu or menus in the site's `config.toml` file.

```
[menu]
[[menu.main]]
  identifier = "pageOne"
  name = "First page"
  weight = 1
  url = "/posts/first-page"
[[menu.main]]
  identifier = "productOne"
  name = "Please view Product one"
  weight = 2
  url = "/posts/product-one"
[[menu.products]]
  identifier = "productsProductOne"
  name = "Product one"
  weight = 1
  url = "/posts/product-one"
```

Comment: menu = ['main', 'pasto'] is superfluous in Option 1.
Also note a weight of 0 doesn't mean before 1, it means unset weight. 
Otherwise, rad.

Comment: Thanks, Rogelio. I added those changes.